# Consider the operator on $C[0,1]$ $T(f)=f(\sin(x))$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the operator on $C[0,1]$ $T(f)=f(\sin(x))$

Show that this operator is not compact. I honestly do not know how to show this. One idea is to find a weakly convergent sequence, whose image does not converge strongly. But I do not know a nice sequence that converges weakly in $C[0,1]$. Another idea is to use Ascoli thoerem. Show that the image of an open ball cannot be equicontinuous. I think that is the solution, i just do not know how to find a sequence of functions that make equicontinuity fail. Seems hard to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f_n(x)=e^{-nx}$ defines  a bounded sequence in $C[0,1]$. If $T$ is compact then $e^{-n\sin x}$ would have a norm convergent subsequence. But this sequence converges point-wise to $1$ when $x=0$ and $0$ when $0<x\leq 1$. Since the limit function is not continuous it follows there cannot be a uniformly convergent subsequence. Hence $T$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

This operator actually has a one-sided inverse. Define the operator $S(f)(x)=f(\arcsin x)$, picking the appropriate branch. Because $1<\pi/2$, $\sin x$ is injective on $[0,1]$, and $\arcsin x$ is continuous on that domain as well. So $TS(f)(x)=T(f(\arcsin(x))=f(\sin(\arcsin(x))=f(x)$. (The same argument goes to show that $S$ is a left as well as right inverse for $T$.)

The compact operators form a two-sided ideal for any algebra of operators, and the identity is compact if and only if the space is finite-dimensional. $C[0,1]$ is not finite-dimensional.